# pyinstaller rejects numpy on Mac (M1, Big Sur & Intel Catalina)

Tags: numpy, pycharm, pyinstaller

pyinstaller have been working fine for me in this program until I began using numpy. The error message seems to be saying that I'm using the wrong version of numpy. I supposed that to mean that version I'm using isn't for the M1 chip. But I've also tried this on an Intel MacBook Air to no avail. Same error message there.  And I looked at the material and the error message refers us to, and tried that too.  Ie, I ddid a pip install of cython, etc.  But.... still no go, and same error message.  I'm making the program in Pycharm, and have tried this using both its venv environment and also the conda environment.
Both give the same result. Ideas anyone?
Here's the error message:

Please note and check the following:

- The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/Users/abMain/zaad/zaad"
- The NumPy version is: "1.21.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/var/folders/n1/26fjs9wx6hz5q9r5kdt5bn3w0000gp/T/_MEIJmdMCM/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/var/folders/n1/26fjs9wx6hz5q9r5kdt5bn3w0000gp/T/_MEIJmdMCM/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/private/var/folders/n1/26fjs9wx6hz5q9r5kdt5bn3w0000gp/T/_MEIJmdMCM/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture